# Counting problem on permutation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many distinct permutations on {$1,2,3,4,5,6$} have cycle structure $(abc)(def)$. The answer is $40$ but how come?

Firstly, I select 3 elements out of 6 by ${6\choose 3}$, then considering each inter-group permutation by $2! * 2!$. Really appreciate if anyone can enlighten me.

There is a similar question by defining structure as $(ab)(cdef)$, my answer is ${6\choose 2}*3!=90$. I don't know if this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You're right in that you have ${6 \choose 3}=20$ choices for $a,b,c$. But because this also determines $d,e,f$, you really only have $10$, because any choice of $a,b,c$ is the same as the choice with the other three values after switching the names of the variables. As an example, consider $\{a,b,c\}=\{1,2,3\}$. This forces $\{d,e,f\}=\{4,5,6\}$. But then you can't count when $\{a,b,c\}=\{4,5,6\}$, as this yields the same set of permutations.

The rest of your analysis is right, so you get $10\times 2\times 2=40$ different permutations.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Choosing 3 out of 6 gives ie ${6 \choose 3} = 20 $.
Suppose chosen ones are $a,b,c$

Now we have something like $(a,b,c)(x,y,z)$

Now simply arrange them in $ 2! $ ways.
ie total ways = $ 2*20 = 40 $